# ContentResult vs. string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string, return-value

I recently was asked why to use `ContentResult` instead of returning `string`. Unfortunately I could not give a better answer than: "It is best practice."

Does anyone have a better answer?

To better understand the question. What's the difference?

```
public ActionResult Foo(){
    return Content("Some string");
}

public string Bar(){
    return "Some string";
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you return something other than an `ActionResult` the default behavior is to create a `ContentResult` wrapping the result of calling `ToString()` on whatever you did return (or `EmptyResult` if you returned `null`). Reasons I can think of to explicitly return `ContentResult`:

- It reinforces the fact that the method is an action, rather than a regular method, so devs are less likely to make mistakes like casually renaming it.
- If in the future you need to specify the content-type you won't need to change the method signature.
- It doesn't hide the `ToString()` call. This doesn't matter if you're returning `string`, but returning a complex type could have unexpected results.

Answer (score 17):

You can't return a string on a method which returns an ActionResult, so this is when you could use a ContentResult to return a plain string like so:

```
public ContentResult Hello()
{
    return Content("hello world!");
}
```

ContentResult by default returns a type of `text/plain`. If you only ever needed to return a string, then you would use the method to return a string

Comment: Why should the message return ActionResult?

Comment: In MVC 4 the default content-type for `ContentResult` is `text/html`. (Source: I just tried it.)

Comment: And if you want to ensure that the content-type of the response is `text/plain` instead of `text/html` then use the overload of the `Content` method that takes a second parameter as the content-type specification.

Comment: Small addition: instead of literally adding "text/plain" as a string, you could use a .NET framework constant like `MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain` or `MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml`. 

Although it only includes some of the most-used MIME types. _( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mime.mediatypenames )_

Answer (score 7):

Two main advantages:

- You can specify the content encoding via the `ContentEncoding` property
- You can specify the content type (ie, 'text/html') via the `ContentType` property

Also, if you want to be OO-clean about it, `ContentResult`, along with all `ActionResult` derived classes follow the [Command Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2004/september/distributed-system-design-using-command-pattern-msmq-and-net#command-pattern-refresher) by providing an `ExecuteResult` command for the MVC pipeline to run.

**UPDATE: 19-Nov-2020**
The original Command Pattern link ([dead link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Design-Patterns-Command-1962d567)) was no longer working so I updated it to reference a similar Microsoft document. Also, to see a great explanation on the Command Pattern, view this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12263/The-Command-Pattern-and-MVC-Architecture).

Answer (score 1):

Returning a ContentResult helps protect your application.

E.g If your application allows input from users, a malicious user might try to parse a javascript text. This will prevent javascript from executing in your application

Answer (score 0):

One difference as i know is :

Content return result without quotations marks if you want.

String return result in Quotations marks all the time.

Answer (score 0):

One another difference is Content result can return different content's result. Like string, Html, JavaScript result etc.

But string return only the string result.