# asp.net MVC routing order

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my demo asp.net mvc application i'm facing an issue with routing. i.e The
action methods with return types other than actionresult or its sub class are not getting called if their route definition are not placed as first and before other route definitions. i.e action methods with return types as void/string/others etc are getting called only if their routes.routemap are placed at the beginning.
for ex if i have and action method say

```
public string method1()
{
}
```

inside a controller cont1, then only if i place the routing code

```
routecollection.maproute("route1","{controller}/{action}",new {controller="cont1",action="method1"}
```

at first before the other routecollection.maproute it is getting called. else it is not getting called. Please let me know the reason behind this.

Comment: Because the first matching route is always executed (the `route1` route you have shown is the same as the `Default` route)

Comment: as @StephenMuecke says 1st matching route always executed, i dont know how you are placing your routes , maybe this article will helpful for you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624181/Routing-Basics-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: It's a good practice to return your string result, wrapped in ContentResult object, which will solve your routing problem, too. Тhere is a detailed discussion on this issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482293/asp-net-mvc-contentresult-vs-string).

Comment: Any of your custom route mappings need to present before the default mapping provided by mvc. else it will always use the default routing.

Answer (score 1):

The default route config should be always at the end of the Route config. Since the route config will parse for matching configuration it will accept and route to that path. So if you specify the default configuration at the beginning it will always match and route to that path.